# grabbing information by joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is going to be a little complicated. Let me start with my tables.

```
clients [src = 0]
---------
clientID       code         company
---------      -------      ---------
1              ABC          ABC Corp
2              DEF          DEF Corp


carriers [src = 1]
---------
clientID       code       company
---------      -------    -------
1              ABC         ABC Inc.
2              JHI         JHI Inc. 


link
--------
contactID        uID      src
---------        -----    ----
1                 1        0
1                 1        1
1                 2        0

contact info
--------------
contactID      fname      lname
---------     -------     --------
1             John        Smith
2              Quincy     Jones
```

So, i'm trying to do a search for say "ABC" on the link table. The link table needs to basically join to either the carriers or clients table depending on the link.src column. It should find two matches, one in the clients and one in the carriers, but since both resolve to contactID (links table) of 1, i should then query the contact info table and return

Found 1 record(s):
John Smith

I hope this makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the desired output if the two matches found do not resolve to the same `contactID` ? What if there is only one match found?

Comment: In the link tbl, they both have contactid of 1

Comment: What if one had `contactID=1`, whereas the other match had  `contactID=2`, or is this case not considered as possible?

Comment: Then it would return John and Quincy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using `left join`:

```
select co.*
from link l left join
     clients cl
     on l.src = 0 and l.uid = cl.code left join
     carriers ca
     on l.src = 1 and l.uid = ca.code left join
     contacts co
     on l.contactid = co.contactid
where 'ABC' in (co.code, cl.code)
```

Comment: clients c ON l.src=0 AND l.uID=cl.clientID?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. First, you `UNION` the `Clients` and `Carriers` tables and add a new column `ContactType` to differentiate one from the other. Use `0` for `Clients` and `1` for `Carriers`, the same as `src`. Then you perform a `LEFT JOIN` to get the desired result.

```
;WITH Clients(ClientID, Code, Company) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'ABC', 'ABC Corp' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'DEF', 'DEF Corp'
)
,Carriers(ClientID, Code, Company) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'ABC', 'ABC Inc.' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'JHI', 'JHI Inc.'
)
,Link(ContactId, UID, Src) AS(
    SELECT 1, 1, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 2, 0
)
,ContactInfo(ContactID, FName, LName) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'John', 'Smith' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Quincy', 'Jones'
)
-- START
,Contact(ContactID, ContactType, Code, Company) AS(
    SELECT
        ClientID, 0, Code, Company
    FROM Clients
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ClientID, 1, Code, Company
    FROM Carriers
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ci.FName,
    ci.LName
FROM Link l
LEFT JOIN Contact c
    ON c.ContactID = l.UID
    AND c.ContactType = l.src
LEFT JOIN ContactInfo ci
    ON ci.ContactID = c.ContactID
WHERE
    c.Code = 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this from a modeling pov. You have two tables with the same type of data in each one, the entity *company*. The only difference between them is their role or relationship to your company. So why not keep them all in the same bucket?

```
Companies:
ID   code   Name
--   ----   ---------
1    ABC    ABC Corp
2    DEF    DEF Corp
3    JHI    JHI Inc.
```

If a particular company could only be a client or a carrier, that designation could be placed in the *Companies* table. Since obviously one company can be both, the designation goes into a separate table. The following shows that company 1, 'ABC', is both a client ('L') and carrier ('R'), company 2 is only a client and company 3 is only a carrier.

```
CompanyRoles:
CompanyID   Type
---------   ----
        1   'L'
        1   'R'
        2   'L'
        3   'R'
```

There is no need to keep multiple copies of the same data just because a company can play multiple roles. If there is role-dependent data, data that is maintained on client but not for carriers, or vice versa, then subtables can keep that.

As for the contacts, if a company has one contact no matter the role, the contact reference can be added to the *Companies* table. If the contact is role dependent, it is added to the *CompanyRoles* table.

```
CompanyRoles:
CompanyID   Type   ContactID
---------   ----   ---------
        1   'L'            1
        1   'R'            2
        2   'L'            3
        3   'R'            4
```

Want to see a list of clients?

```
select  c.ID as ClientID, c.Code as ClientCode, c.Name as ClientName,
        ci.ContactName
from    Companies c
join    CompanyRoles cr
    on  cr.CompanyID = c.ID
    and cr.Type      = 'L'
left join Contacts ct    -- In case no contact is currently defined
    on  ct.ContactID = cr.ContactID
join    ClientSpecificData csd
    on  csd.ClientID = c.ID;
```

Want to see a list of carriers?

```
select  c.ID as CarrierID, c.Code as CarrierCode, c.Name as CarrierName,
        ci.ContactName
from    Companies c
join    CompanyRoles cr
    on  cr.CompanyID = c.ID
    and cr.Type      = 'R'
left join Contacts ct    -- In case no contact is currently defined
    on  ct.ContactID = cr.ContactID
join    CarrierSpecificData csd
    on  csd.ClientID = c.ID;
```

You can create views on the last two queries to provide a single data source for those apps that deal with only Clients or only Carriers. Triggers on the views can deal with incoming DML statements as needed to route the data to the appropriate tables.

As you can see, the queries are clean and simple. Data integrity is easy and scalability is not an issue. What more could you want?